# JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 1531 (char 1530)

Tags: python, json, pandas, error-handling

```
i=3470
order_dispatched= pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(3480):
    js = json.loads(sheet_order_dispatched.ORDER_DETAILS_SUP[i])
    df_converted = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(js)
    df_converted['ORDER_ID'] = sheet_order_dispatched['ORDER_ID'][i]
    #dataframe with actual indexing
    df1 = pd.concat([order_dispatched,df_converted])
   #dataframe with continous indexing
    df11 = pd.concat([order_dispatched,df_converted], ignore_index= True)
```

Was getting this error in a row, I removed that row.
But then I start getting same error in row above. Not able to understand the changes need to made

Comment: Show the content of a not working row before trying to convert to json with
    js = json.loads(sheet_order_dispatched.ORDER_DETAILS_SUP[i])

Comment: Thanx . issue resolved